# regex search two expressions combining python

Tags: python, regex-group, python-re

I am new to Python and Regular Expressions. As I am doing online course, came across this simple task. It Checks whether for Standard Sentence : Line starts with uppercase letter and ends with period or Question mark. This is my working code, but it uses two re.search, which need to reduce to one. If I add both regex exp. it gives different Output.

This is My Code:

```
import re
def check_sentence(text):
  result = re.search(r"[\.\?]$", text) and re.search(r"^[A-Z]", text)
  return result != None

print(check_sentence("Is this is a sentence?")) # True
print(check_sentence("is this is a sentence?")) # False
print(check_sentence("Hello")) # False
print(check_sentence("1-2-3-GO!")) # False
print(check_sentence("A star is born.")) # True
```

I need single expression. Combining this r'^[A-Z]' and r'[.?]$'. But If I just use : r'^[A-Z][.?]$' it gives different O/P.

Thanks for help with explanation.

Comment: Do you know https://regexr.com/ ? I think you miss `.*` at the middle: `^[A-Z].*[\.\?]$`.

Comment: For https://regexr.com/, don't forget to check in "Flags" menu : "multiline".

Answer (score 0):

You can merge like this:

```
import re
def check_sentence(text):
  result = re.search(r"^[A-Z].*[\.\?]$", text)
  return result != None
```